How to avoid context specific "Incompatible return value type" error from Mypy
I'm new to Mypy, and I have two functions with the following type annotations:
def to_number(value: str): -> int | float
    # checks whether 'value' is compatible with int or float 
    # and converts to the appropriate type
    return value

def to_unicode_decimal: value: str): -> int
    # checks that value is hex    
    decimal = to_number(value) # converts to decimal
    # checks that decimal is within unicode range
    return decimal

Even though to_number() has the potential to return int or float, to_unicode_decimal() ensures that the return value always will be hex by asking the re module for a match. As far as I know, hexes cannot be floats unless specifically converted.
Regardless, Mypy conmplains: Incompatible return value type (got "int | float", expected "int")
How should this error be addressed?
So far I've only gotten around it by # type: ignore for the particular lines where the variable containing the return value is used, but this is not ideal.
